# How do I loop through the code with the variable list?

Tags: loops, for-loop

I am trying unsuccessfully to create a loop that runs through list_vars and the code specified below (dep1 would change for each loop to the next variable in list_vars). Is a for loop the best option and if so could you please advise on how to create it?

## import data

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep=',')
group <- read.csv("group.csv", header = TRUE, sep=',')
```

## create a list of variables to loop through

```
list_vars <- list(c("dep1",
                "dep2",
                "dep3",
                "dep4",
                "dep5",
                "dep6",
                "dep7",
                "dep8",
                "dep9"))
```

### Run following code for each variable in list_vars

```
full.model <- lm(dep1 ~ indep1 
              + indep2
              + indep3
              + indep4
              + indep5
              + indep6
              + indep7
              + indep8
              + indep9
              + indep10,
              data = data)

step.model <- stepAIC(full.model, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)

dep1_regr <- predict(step.model, newdata = data)

data <- cbind(data, dep1_regr)

dep1_data <- select(data, country, impute_q, UNIQUE, weight, dep1_regr, dep1) 

write.xlsx(dep1_data, "dep1.xlsx", sheetName="dep1", 
           col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE)

write.xlsx(group, "dep1.xlsx", sheetName="group", 
           col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a foreach loop is better for this...

```
foreach (variable in yourList){

   do Something/print
}
```